# Крайний Север: оба ли слова с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Меня вчера заклинило: никак не мог вспомнить, как пишется "Крайний Север" — оба слова с прописной или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, оба слова пишутся с прописной буквы *Крайний Север*. [gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EA%F0%E0%E9%ED%E8%E9+%F1%E5%E2%E5%F0&all=x)